# Show that a 2nd derivative is zero given that an interior point attains the same value as the boundary points

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

This looks a lot like Rolle's Theorem, but I don't quite know how to start cracking it. Any help would be appreciated.

> $f$ is twice-differentiable on $[a,b]$.
>
> $f(a)=f(c)=f(b)$ for some $c$ in $(a,b)$.
>
> Prove that $f''(d)=0$ for some $d$ in $(a,b)$.

Comment: By and large, everything mathematicians do is proving theorems. You might do better with a more informative title so people can tell if this question is in their specific domain of knowledge.

Comment: Do Rolle for $f$ on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$. Then do Rolle for $f'$ between the two values you got from first step.

Comment: @julien Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=f'(x)$ and apply Rolle's theorem to $g$.  You need to show that there are two points in $(a,b)$ such that $g=0$, which needs two more applications of Rolle's.